# Row Echelon Form - Change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Here is a row echelon form and original matrix:

[image]

My text says:

> Our problem is to find bases for the column spaces of  and . Those
>   spaces are different (just look at the matrices!) but their dimensions
>   are the same.

How come the spaces the matrix spans have changed? No combination of the columns of U will ever give me anything in the third entry like A's columns so how are these two equivalent?

> The first and third columns of  are a basis for its column space.
>   They are the columns with pivots. Every other column is a combination
>   of those two. Furthermore, the same is true of the original —even
>   though its columns are different. The pivot columns of  are a basis
>   for its column space.

Has the basis of my matrix changed? Can anyone comment as to what happens to my original basis?

Comment: Doing row operations changes the column space, in general.

Comment: But if those are operations that are supposed to preserve the original relation, then why does this happen?

Comment: In row operations, you are combining rows with different operations so you are preserving the row space (and  also the null space) but not the column space. So for a basis for column space of $A$ look at the pivot columns in $U$, the corresponding columns in $A$ will form a basis for the column space of $A$.

Comment: It's an effect of doing row operations:   relations between the rows can change.  However,  relations between corresponding columns are preserved,  as are the row space and null space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are equivalent because$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 & 0 \\ 5 & -2 & 1\end{bmatrix}.A=U.$$And there is no such thing as the basis of a matrix. What happens is that the span of the columns of $A$ has the same dimension as the span of the columns of $U$. But it is quit easy to see that the span of the columns of $U$ is the space spanned by its first and third columns. So both column spaces have dimension $2$.

Comment: I did not the purpose of your matrix calculation. What implies they are equivalent?

Comment: Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are equivalent if there are invertible matrices $M$ and $N$ such that $A=M.B.N$. My computations show that your matrices $A$ and $U$ are equivalent.

Comment: But you only have 2 matrices on one side while your equation says 3. Are you saying they are 'similar matrices'?

Comment: No, I am **not** saying that they are similar. That would make no sense. And what I wrote is equivalent to$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 & 0 \\ 5 & -2 & 1\end{bmatrix}.A.\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}=U.$$

Comment: In that case, can you point me to more reading or theorems on your statement "Two matrices  and  are equivalent if there are invertible matrices  and  such that =.."?

Comment: I read somewhere " That this is so is because doing an elementary row operation just amounts to expressing all columns in a different basis. " Can you say how this happens?

Comment: Try the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence).